# Tweepy timed out connection error

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, while-loop, exception, tweepy

i read anything that is to read regarding this error:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twitter.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)
As soon as the error shows the script starts getting followers from the first page. 
It seems that it shows up when there is a connection error at the time of retrieving the data from twitter. Any ideea will be very much appreciated as o can't find more info about the issue. How can i handle the exception so i can resume the cursor from where it stopped without starting all over from the first page? I assume i need to save the cursor object and resume from there.

```
import tweepy
import csv
import time
from time import sleep
import datetime
from requests.exceptions import Timeout, ConnectionError
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import ReadTimeoutError, ProtocolError

consumer_key = 'xxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxx'
access_token = 'xxx'
access_token_secret = 'xxx'


auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)


api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True, compression=True)

csvFile = open('followers.csv', 'a')

csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

while True:
try:
    for follower in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name='twitterscreenname', count='200').items():
        print(follower.screen_name)
        csvWriter.writerow([follower.screen_name])
except tweepy.TweepError as e:
    print (e.reason)
    if 'Failed to send request:' in e.reason:
        print ('timeout error caught.')
        time.sleep(100)
        continue
except (Timeout, SSLError, ConnectionError, ReadTimeoutError, ProtocolError) as exc:
    print ('2nd exception')
    time.sleep(150)
    continue
```